# is there any example of Tensorflow inference with multiple GPUs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I just got an intern position in which I need to help them with serving inference requests on multiple GPUs. However, the available Github resource I could find are all about training.
Is there any example using multiple GPU to do inference in Tensorflow (python).

Comment: Checkout this - https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed

Comment: did you find something to do only inference using gpu ?

Comment: I have been looking for such an example for last couple of weeks. Most of the answers direct to cifar example which seems does not work. When you run on single GPU the usage is closed to 100% but when you run on multiple (say 4) usage of each GPU is like around 50%.